# storing values of list

Tags: java

I have a Map , but I want the values of the map to be of type ArrayList

```
Map m = new HashMap();
```

since the value of the Key 'A' would itself have multiple values eg. key 'A' has values 10,20,30 please advise how to achieve this, I have created the first step below

```
LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>> A = new LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

please advise how to add the multiple values in the list next and store it along with the Map in put operation

Comment: whats wrong with your current solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then this seems to be the right way to me, all you then need to do is either:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("10");
strings.add("20");
strings.add("30");

A.put(strings);
```

Or you can:

```
A.put(Arrays.asList("10", "20", "30"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this -

```
LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>> A = new LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("10");
list.add("20");
list.add("30");
A.put("a", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("xyz");
// ....

Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Key", list);
```

Answer (score 0):

as I know that, you can use Apache MultiValueMap. It meets your requirement.http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a program.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>> A = new LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        A.put("1", list);

        //add new values
        list = A.get("1");
        if(list!=null){
            list.add("2");
        }else{
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("2");
        }
        A.put("1", list);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace **List** with **TreeSet** and if the all values are ***integer*** then it will be better to use **Integer** instead of **String**

Here in example taken Integer type while just replace it with String it will work fine as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>> lhm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.add(20);
        set.add(10);
        set.add(30);
        set.add(50);
        set.add(70);
        set.add(60);
        set.add(90);
        set.addAll(Arrays.asList(22,33,44,55));
        lhm.put("A",set);
        
        System.out.println(lhm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on a good start. Beacuse your value are stored in an ArrayList, the map.put() operation will append the new value to the arraylist.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;


public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        //Create a list for A
        ArrayList<String> someValuesForA = new ArrayList<>();
        someValuesForA.add("10");
        someValuesForA.add("20");
        someValuesForA.add("30");

        //Add A and the list to the map
        map.put("A", someValuesForA);
        System.out.println(map.get("A"));

        //Add a new value to the list
        map.get("A").add("40");
        System.out.println(map.get("A"));

        //In case you want to add a key with no initial values
        map.put("B", new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

[image]